# PYTHON: What is necessary to be able to call a method from within the same class?

Tags: python, windows, methods

I feel like I am missing a major piece of how this code is working, or something really strange is going on.  I have included a method called "handle" which is being passed to thread.start_new_thread as a parameter, however it seems that this method is not being recognized/executed.  Even within the PythonWin editor, when you type "self." it will usually prepopulate a list of recognized options, and handle is not showing up in this version, but in a working version of this file it does show up within the editor.

Here is the code:

(lots of imports go here)

```
class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "flaspsrv"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Flash Policy Server"
    _svc_description_ = "Initialize Flash Policy Server"

    def __init__(self,args):
        logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Uploads\\testing.log', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except AttributeError:
            # AttributeError catches Python built without IPv6
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            # socket.error catches OS with IPv6 disabled
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            logging.info('Listening on port 843')
            self.sock.bind(('localhost', 843))
            self.sock.listen(5)

        try:
            while True:
                thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error accepting connection: %s' % (e[1],))

    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        logging.info('Temp2')
        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (addr[0],addr[1])
        try:
            logging.info('Connection from %s' % (addrstr,))
            with contextlib.closing(conn):
                # It's possible that we won't get the entire request in
                # a single recv, but very unlikely.
                request = conn.recv(1024).strip()
                if request != '<policy-file-request/>\0':
                    logging.info('Unrecognized request from %s: %s' % (addrstr, request))
                    return
                logging.info('Valid request received from %s' % (addrstr,))
                fo = file('flashpolicy.xml', 'rb')
                conn.sendall(fo.read(10001))
                logging.info('Sent policy file to %s' % (addrstr,))
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest program that still exhibits the error, and then paste that entire program into your question. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: "*it seems that this method is not being recognized/executed*" - what is the precise error message including traceback?

Comment: I don't receive any error messages.  This script is used to install a service, and upon running the service is supposed to be executing the "main".  The service installs correctly, will even run and writes to the log file as well as LISTENS on port 843 UNTIL i try to make a connection, at which point the service moves itself to STOPPED.  I am unsure of any way to turn this into an error log as I am very inexperienced with python and unsure where to start building this from the ground up. The first line comment in the handle method never prints to the log file.

Comment: Additionally, I know that the general method of this code executes flawlessly as I have another python script which is not a service but runs absolutely flawlessly, but requires a command prompt window to remain open. I have also looked at routes of trying to run a python script from within a python script to simply call the working script from this "service" script, and that all fails as well despite working flawlessly as a single line script in several different methodologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())
```

to

```
thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, *self.sock.accept())
```

From the documentation of [socket.accept()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept), this socket method returns a tuple `(conn, address)`, where as your handler accepts three parameters (including a reference to self).

The second and third parameter of [thread.start_new_thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) is the `args` (positional arguments) and `kwargs` (key word arguments) that are supposed to be passed to the callback registered with the threading module. So unless you unpack the arguments from `socket.accept()`, you would likely be receiving a `Type Error`.

So you need to unpack the return tuple from `self.socket` before passing as an argument to handle.

Comment: I tried doing this and it is still performing the same way as before, runs fine until connection attempt and service moves to stopped. I did also try removing the self parameter (as I admittedly don't know what it's even for, I just avoided changing things I didn't understand) to see if it would work with just the two parameters, and again same behavior.

Comment: Also, if you have any suggestions on ways that I can narrow the problem down further by just trying to print the parameters its supposed to be returning to the log or something I am more than happy to try anything at this point, I just was not sure of how to do something like that. I'm a python newbie.

Comment: I tried creating a copy of this script which has a second method in it which only accepts two parameters (conn, addr) and then simply made this method write the variables to the log, and the log file does still does not print the variables.  Something is not making the connection and I am lacking to understand what.